# Job scheduling service library for flex (similar to quartz in java)

Tags: apache-flex, air, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

I am searching for a flex library for job scheduling. I know the Timer API, but this is not exactly what I am searching for. Here is (one of) my usecase for my AIR application:

- Try to ping to website xyz every 15 minutes
- Every first monday of a month try connect to website abcdefg
- ..

So I am searching for a library like quartz in java, just a small sweet library for executing cron(like) jobs.

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex is used to build client side tools.  It is not a service that runs constantly.  While you can set up the timer to do something like connect to a web site every fifteen minutes, it will only work if the application is up and running.  For something like that, you're best bet is getting a push server in place, such as LiveCycle or GraniteDS and pushing data to the server when needed.

You can also write some logic to connect to a web site on the first Monday of a month.

All that said, neither of these would if the application is not running.  I do not thing Flex is the appropriate tool for cron-like jobs.

I would suggest researching elsewhere.